# Attaching scrollbar to listbox in tkinter window python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pycharm

Need help in attaching the scrollbar to the listbox.I have tried several things & obviously I am not doing something correct. Any help/guidance will be really appreciated. I have attached a snapshot of how the tkinter window looks like.

```
from tkinter import *

app = Tk()

label1_text = StringVar()
part_label = Label(app, bg='#dfe3ee', text='Check1', font=('bold',12), pady=10, padx=20)
part_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
label1_entry = Entry(app, textvariable=label1_text)
label1_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

label2_text = StringVar()
part_label = Label(app, bg='#dfe3ee', text='Check1', font=('bold', 12), pady=7, padx=20)
part_label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
label2_entry = Entry(app, textvariable=label2_text)
label2_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)

label3_text = StringVar()
part_label = Label(app, bg='#dfe3ee', text='Check3', font=('bold', 12), pady=20)
part_label.grid(row=0, column=2)
label3_entry = Entry(app, textvariable=label3_text)
label3_entry.grid(row=0, column=3)

label4 = StringVar()
part_label = Label(app, bg='#dfe3ee', text='check4', font=('bold', 12), pady=7)
part_label.grid(row=1, column=2)
label4_entry = Entry(app, textvariable=label4)
label4_entry.grid(row=1, column=3)

B1_btn = Button(app, bg='#cd8de5', text='Button1',font=('bold', 11), width=12)
B1_btn.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=0, pady=5)

B2_btn = Button(app, bg='#cd8de5', text='Button2',font=('bold', 11), width=12 )
B2_btn.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=0, pady=5)

B3_btn = Button(app, bg='#d5a6e6', text='close',font=('bold', 11), width=12)
B3_btn.grid(row=50, column=2, sticky='E')

output_list = Listbox(app, height=20, width=100, border=5)
output_list.grid(row=20, column=0, columnspan=3, rowspan=6, pady=20, padx=20)

scrollbar = Scrollbar(app)
scrollbar.grid(row=20, column =3, rowspan=5, sticky=(N+S))

output_list.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.configure(command=output_list.yview)

app.title('Test Tool')
app.geometry('900x900')
app.configure(bg='#dfe3ee')

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't think you need `row=20` and `row=50`. Adjust your items so that there is no empty rows/columns in between and think about the layout again. Your layout seems inconsistent so it is hard to guess what layout you are trying to make. But to fix the problem I would just make a frame and put listbox and scrollbar in it, that should fix the problem

Comment: WHAT exactly is your problem? The scrollbar works with the Listbox as expected and it is where you have placed it in the grid.

Comment: `scrollbar.grid(row=20, column =3, rowspan=6, sticky=(W+N+S))` puts the scrollbar to the left side of the grid. 
`output_list.grid(row=20, column=0, columnspan=3, rowspan=6)` lets the scrollbar 'stick' to the listbox. Is it what you are after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following small changes the scrollbar 'sticks' to the listbox:

`scrollbar.grid(row=20, column =3, rowspan=6, sticky=(W+N+S))` puts the scrollbar to the left side of the grid.

`output_list.grid(row=20, column=0, columnspan=3, rowspan=6)` let the scrollbar 'stick' to the listbox.

[image]

The code below let you scroll the with items filled listbox with the scrollbar:

```
from tkinter import *

app = Tk()

label1_text = StringVar()
part_label = Label(app, bg='#dfe3ee', text='Check1', font=('bold',12), pady=10, padx=20)
part_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
label1_entry = Entry(app, textvariable=label1_text)
label1_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

label2_text = StringVar()
part_label = Label(app, bg='#dfe3ee', text='Check1', font=('bold', 12), pady=7, padx=20)
part_label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
label2_entry = Entry(app, textvariable=label2_text)
label2_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)

label3_text = StringVar()
part_label = Label(app, bg='#dfe3ee', text='Check3', font=('bold', 12), pady=20)
part_label.grid(row=0, column=2)
label3_entry = Entry(app, textvariable=label3_text)
label3_entry.grid(row=0, column=3)

label4 = StringVar()
part_label = Label(app, bg='#dfe3ee', text='check4', font=('bold', 12), pady=7)
part_label.grid(row=1, column=2)
label4_entry = Entry(app, textvariable=label4)
label4_entry.grid(row=1, column=3)

B1_btn = Button(app, bg='#cd8de5', text='Button1',font=('bold', 11), width=12)
B1_btn.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=0, pady=5)

B2_btn = Button(app, bg='#cd8de5', text='Button2',font=('bold', 11), width=12 )
B2_btn.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=0, pady=5)

B3_btn = Button(app, bg='#d5a6e6', text='close',font=('bold', 11), width=12)
B3_btn.grid(row=50, column=2, sticky='E')

output_list = Listbox(app, height=20, width=100, border=5)
output_list.grid(row=20, column=0, columnspan=3, rowspan=6) # was: , pady=20, padx=20)
for i in range(40): 
    output_list.insert(i, i+1)
scrollbar = Scrollbar(app)
scrollbar.grid(row=20, column =3, rowspan=6, sticky=(W+N+S)) # was: (N+S)

output_list.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.configure(command=output_list.yview)

app.title('Test Tool')
app.geometry('900x900')
app.configure(bg='#dfe3ee')

app.mainloop()
```

Initially the scrollbar had not the right raw span and was placed in the center of the grid column. And the listbox  paddding prevented 'sticking' the scrollbar to the listbox:

[image]

If you remove `for i in range(40): output_list.insert(i, i+1)` from the code above you get a blank list box as follows:

[image]

Tkinter grid manager allows to force row and columns to have a minimal size what makes even empty rows and columns 'visible'.

With:

```
app.grid_columnconfigure( 0, minsize=20)
app.grid_columnconfigure( 5, minsize=20)
app.grid_rowconfigure(   27, minsize=20)
app.grid_rowconfigure(   51, minsize=20)
```

you can create appropriate space around the in the grid placed widgets.

The complete code looks now as follows:

```
from tkinter import *

app = Tk()

app.grid_columnconfigure( 0, minsize=20)
app.grid_columnconfigure( 5, minsize=20)
app.grid_rowconfigure(   27, minsize=20)
app.grid_rowconfigure(   51, minsize=20)

label1_text = StringVar()
part_label = Label(app, bg='#dfe3ee', text='Check1', font=('bold',12), pady=10, padx=20)
part_label.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)
label1_entry = Entry(app, textvariable=label1_text)
label1_entry.grid(row=0, column=2)

label2_text = StringVar()
part_label = Label(app, bg='#dfe3ee', text='Check1', font=('bold', 12), pady=7, padx=20)
part_label.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)
label2_entry = Entry(app, textvariable=label2_text)
label2_entry.grid(row=1, column=2)

label3_text = StringVar()
part_label = Label(app, bg='#dfe3ee', text='Check3', font=('bold', 12), pady=20)
part_label.grid(row=0, column=3)
label3_entry = Entry(app, textvariable=label3_text)
label3_entry.grid(row=0, column=4)

label4 = StringVar()
part_label = Label(app, bg='#dfe3ee', text='check4', font=('bold', 12), pady=7)
part_label.grid(row=1, column=3)
label4_entry = Entry(app, textvariable=label4)
label4_entry.grid(row=1, column=4)

B1_btn = Button(app, bg='#cd8de5', text='Button1',font=('bold', 11), width=12)
B1_btn.grid(row=3, column=2, padx=0, pady=5)

B2_btn = Button(app, bg='#cd8de5', text='Button2',font=('bold', 11), width=12 )
B2_btn.grid(row=4, column=2, padx=0, pady=5)

B3_btn = Button(app, bg='#d5a6e6', text='close',font=('bold', 11), width=12)
B3_btn.grid(row=50, column=3, sticky='E')

output_list = Listbox(app, height=20, width=100, border=5)
output_list.grid(row=20, column=1, columnspan=3, rowspan=6) # was: , pady=20, padx=20)
# for i in range(40): 
#     output_list.insert(i, i+1)
scrollbar = Scrollbar(app)
scrollbar.grid(row=20, column =4, rowspan=6, sticky=(W+N+S)) # was: (N+S)

output_list.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.configure(command=output_list.yview)

app.title('Test Tool')
# app.geometry('900x900')
app.configure(bg='#dfe3ee')

app.mainloop()
```

and results in:

[image]

Usage of the grid manager may be easier grouping the grid placements together to 'see' the grid layout 'mirrored' already in the code.
Now it becomes possible to 'see' where it is necessary to add spacing between the widgets by forcing minimum size of rows or columns. Below code rewritten to group the grid placements with added space between the buttons and the listbox:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Entry, Label, Listbox
app = Tk()

# Creating widgets (to place them later into the grid): 
label1_text, label2_text, label3_text, label4_text = 4*[StringVar()]

label1_label = Label(app, bg='#dfe3ee', text='Check1', font=('bold',12), pady=10, padx=20)
label1_entry = Entry(app, textvariable=label1_text)

label2_label = Label(app, bg='#dfe3ee', text='Check1', font=('bold', 12), pady=7, padx=20)
label2_entry = Entry(app, textvariable=label2_text)

label3_label = Label(app, bg='#dfe3ee', text='Check3', font=('bold', 12), pady=20)
label3_entry = Entry(app, textvariable=label3_text)

label4_label = Label(app, bg='#dfe3ee', text='check4', font=('bold', 12), pady=7)
label4_entry = Entry(app, textvariable=label4_text)

B1_btn = Button(app, bg='#cd8de5', text='Button1',font=('bold', 11), width=12)
B2_btn = Button(app, bg='#cd8de5', text='Button2',font=('bold', 11), width=12 )

output_list = Listbox(app, height=20, width=100, border=5)
# for i in range(40): 
#     output_list.insert(i, i+1)
scrollbar = Scrollbar(app)
output_list.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.configure(command=output_list.yview)

B3_btn = Button(app, bg='#d5a6e6', text='close',font=('bold', 11), width=12)

# Placement of created widgets into the grid layout: 
app.grid_columnconfigure(        0, minsize=20) # left  'border'
label1_label.grid(row= 0, column=1, sticky=W)
label1_entry.grid(row= 0, column=2)
label3_label.grid(row= 0, column=3)
label3_entry.grid(row= 0, column=4)
label2_label.grid(row= 1, column=1, sticky=W)
label2_entry.grid(row= 1, column=2)
label4_label.grid(row= 1, column=3)
label4_entry.grid(row= 1, column=4)
app.grid_columnconfigure(        5, minsize=20) # right 'border'
B1_btn.grid(      row= 3, column=2, padx=0, pady=5)
B2_btn.grid(      row= 4, column=2, padx=0, pady=5)
app.grid_rowconfigure( 5, minsize=20) # space between B2_btn and output_list
output_list.grid( row=20, column=1, columnspan=3, rowspan=6) # was: , pady=20, padx=20)
scrollbar.grid(   row=20, column=4,               rowspan=6, sticky=(W+N+S)) # was: (N+S)
app.grid_rowconfigure(27, minsize=20) # space between output_list and B3_btn
B3_btn.grid(      row=50, column=3, sticky='E')
app.grid_rowconfigure(51, minsize=20) # bottom 'border'

app.title('Test Tool')
# app.geometry('900x900')
app.configure(bg='#dfe3ee')

app.mainloop()
```

giving:

[image]

Comment: Ty so much claudio however I am looking for a blank screen in the listbox. It is almost good with below code

Comment: how can i add another pic so that you can see the result and code to this string?

Comment: You get a blank listbox removing `for i in range(40): 
    output_list.insert(i, i+1)` from the code above. See updated answer.

Comment: You get an image added to your question text with Ctrl+G or by clicking the image icon upon the text input area.

Comment: See updated code for how to add cushion space using only the grid manager to arrange the widgets.

Comment: Claudio, once again TY so much. I think the main problem was the 1. padx to the out_put listbox and adding W to the scrollbar grid to make it W+N+S. Adjusted rest of the  things by trial and error, and all is good now. The main mistake [(which I am not correcting for now :) ] is my output box as a list,should be text box. The listbox is meant for output area for my program,it shoud not have been a listbox but a textbox but now everything is writing properly to the listbox so I will avoid making any changes. Also I did not use the for loop because it shows the index which is not needed

Answer (score 0):

The listbox and the scrollbar works without any problem but your layout looks inconsistent. A good way to make layout with lots of widgets is, using the `Frame` to *group* the widgets and then place those widgets on the window.

It will look more professional and easy to manage once you group them up because now you will just have to deal with a frame inside your main app. Say you want to change the position of a label later, any change to it can mess up the entire layout of the app. But using frames, the change of position will be contained inside the frame only.

Look at how you can organize your widgets:

```
frame_app = Frame(app,background='#dfe3ee') # A frame for the top section. Also if you dont give background to the frame it will fill empty spaces with default background
frame_app.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky=W)

label1_text = StringVar()
# Set the parent to the frame instead of the app
part_label = Label(frame_app, bg='#dfe3ee', text='Check1', font=('bold',12), pady=10, padx=20)
part_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
label1_entry = Entry(frame_app, textvariable=label1_text)
label1_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

label2_text = StringVar()
part_label = Label(frame_app, bg='#dfe3ee', text='Check1', font=('bold', 12), pady=7, padx=20)
part_label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
label2_entry = Entry(frame_app, textvariable=label2_text)
label2_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)

label3_text = StringVar()
part_label = Label(frame_app, bg='#dfe3ee', text='Check3', font=('bold', 12), pady=20)
part_label.grid(row=0, column=2)
label3_entry = Entry(frame_app, textvariable=label3_text)
label3_entry.grid(row=0, column=3)

label4 = StringVar()
part_label = Label(frame_app, bg='#dfe3ee', text='check4', font=('bold', 12), pady=7)
part_label.grid(row=1, column=2)
label4_entry = Entry(frame_app, textvariable=label4)
label4_entry.grid(row=1, column=3)

B1_btn = Button(frame_app, bg='#cd8de5', text='Button1',font=('bold', 11), width=12)
B1_btn.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=0, pady=5)

B2_btn = Button(frame_app, bg='#cd8de5', text='Button2',font=('bold', 11), width=12 )
B2_btn.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=0, pady=5)

# Make a frame for the listbox and scrollbar
frame_listbox = Frame(app)
frame_listbox.grid(row=1,column=0)

output_list = Listbox(frame_listbox, height=20, width=100, border=5)
output_list.grid(row=0, column=0)

scrollbar = Scrollbar(frame_listbox)
scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=(N+S)) # Also can say sticky='ns'
    
output_list.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.configure(command=output_list.yview)

# Outside the frame and in the main window because this button does not really fit the context of any frames
B3_btn = Button(app, bg='#d5a6e6', text='close',font=('bold', 11), width=12)
B3_btn.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='E')
```

Here you are grouping the top section widgets to be inside a single frame and then you are using `grid` on that frame to place this on the first row. Then the listbox and scrollbar is placed onto another frame and then gridded onto the next row. This way you can see that you don't need `row=20` or `<column/row>span` and just account for the needed rows and at the same time have a more organized layout.

To test out if the scrollbar works, you will have to insert enough items to fill the entire `height` of the listbox:

```
for i in range(50): # Dummy data
    output_list.insert(END, i)
```

---

Obviously you can also now manually add more `padx` and `pady` if you want to edit the space between widgets in the top section, those will be upto you.

Comment: Ty so much for the support Claudio and Delrius and it is almost good however I am now missing some cushion space on the left side. code is

Comment: @vicky I recommend you upload an image with the layout you desire and we can work the rest out from there

Comment: @vicky May I know as to why this answer was removed as the correct answer? Is there any mistake on the code that I haven't addressed?

Comment: Hi Delrius, I am just seeing your message. I dont know, I just marked one the answer provided by claudio because the N+S+W worked, but I didnt remove anything nor I have the rights.

Comment: @vicky With all respect to claudio, the approach where you keep row or column at something like 250 where there are unused columns in between is kind of a wrong way. Using frames to group widget should be the right approach. But it all depends on which answer you felt is right or wrong

Comment: I really appreciate your opinion. I am just learning and for now I somehow wanted to get tKinter window in shape anyhow :) I know there are various methods to do something and I would certainly take your comment into consideration when trying again or practicing. Once again, Ty ! for the support and comment, really appreciate.